# Expression: wanted the skinny on

Tags: expressions

Is there an expression like *wanted the skinny on*?

I can hazard a guess on the meaning of the phrase but will be grateful if anyone can tell me the exact meaning.

Here is the exact quote:

> I'm a faculty person and just *wanted the skinny on* how my students can best utilize your services?

Comment: General Reference.  [skinny](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=skinny&defid=1235981) 
"The skinny" is a slang term that refers to inside information. Similar to the "low down".

Comment: Wiktionary's sense 2 for noun *[skinny](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/skinny#Noun)* is "The details or facts; especially, those obtained by gossip or rumor."

Comment: I don't believe that this is general reference. It is American slang that is not listed in all dictionaries, and I, for one, have never comes across such usage.

Answer (score 3):

According to the ODO this is [American slang](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/skinny):

> (the skinny) US confidential information on a particular person or topic:
>   *net managers who want **the skinny** on the latest in computer security*

According to [Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skinny?show=1&t=1345530847), it is synonymous with *dope*, *scoop*, *lowdown*, etc. The [origin of the term](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=skinny) is uncertain:

> In the sense of "the truth" it is World War II military slang, perhaps from the notion of the "naked" truth.

Comment: Another (informal) synonym would be [*scuttlebutt*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scuttlebutt).

Answer (score 1):

While [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/skinny#Noun) mentions "The details or facts; especially, those obtained by gossip or rumor", the usage I came across is "the short version", an informal summary, as opposed to "the full story".

In particular, in your example, the faculty person doesn't want any secrets or rumors, they want you to summarize the information in one or two sentences without wasting their time.